# PHP, foreach doesnt return an array but array_map with same code returns an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-map

I want the `foreach` to return arrays but it just returns a single array. But the `array_map with` same code does.

- What is the correct way of getting the arrays out of the `foreach`.
- Why does `foreach` behaves differently than `array_map`.

---

Inside the **file** *(userdata.php)*

```
Reme:Reme1991@jourrapide.com
george bush:GeorgeBush@gmail.com
obama:obama@gmail.com
```

---

Using **`array_map`**

```
function registered_users(){
 $file_user = file('userdata.php');
    return array_map(function($user){
        return explode(':',$user);
    },$file_user);
    } //returns the exploded array correctly.
```

---

Using **`foreach`**

```
function registered_users(){
     $file_user = file('userdata.php');
        foreach ($file_user as $user) {
            return explode(':',$user);
    }
 }// returns Array ( [0] => Reme [1] => Reme1991@jourrapide.com )
```

Comment: foreach isn't a function that returns a value, it's a language construct.  You can't use it like that (or rather you can, but returning within a foreach terminates it prematurely which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: @GordonM Even I have used a return in the `array_map` why is it not moving out ?

Comment: You're not using a return in an array_map.  You're using a return in the callback function that array_map is executing.  It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `array_map()` iterates over all elements in the array.... the `foreach()` would do the same except that your `return` is jumping out of it on the first iteration.

```
function registered_users(){
    $users = [];
    $file_user = file('userdata.php');
    foreach ($file_user as $user) {
        $users[] = explode(':',$user);
    }
    return $users;
}
```

**EDIT**

In response to your question "Why doesn't a return from `array_map` terminate the iteration?"

Because `array_map()` is a function that loops/iterates every element in the array, executing a **"callback"** function against each element. Your return is in the "callback" function, which acts on one individual array element at a time, and is called multiple times by `array_map()`, once for each element of the array in turn.

The `return` in your "callback" is simply returning a modified value for that **one** individual element (the current element in the `array_map()` loop) to the `array_map()` function.... it's telling `array_map()` what the new element value should be.

The `array_map()` function itself can't be interrupted: it will then continue iterating over the next element, sending that in turn to the "callback" function until it has done so for every element in the array.

Comment: Even I have used a return in the `array_map` why is it not moving out ?